# What Windows drivers survive a wipe / reset?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-intune

We are fully onboard with the modern mobile device management dream. Managing PCs with Intune and onboard them using Autopilot. These PCs are purchased with a clean install of Windows. For those we are migrating, we install a clean copy. When a PC moves between users or roles, we Wipe / reset it. We also rely on Windows Update to maintain its drivers (see [Drivers 101](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/deployment-service-for-driver-updates-public-preview-coming-soon/ba-p/2914212#Drivers101)). Normally, this works great. However, we have recently found a couple new models who's NIC and hard drive drivers are missing after a Windows reset. I am assuming the difference must either be:

1. Those that fail had a class of driver pre-installed that does not survive the wipe.
2. Or, for those that do work, Windows must have a default driver.

Does anyone know what the difference is or how to determine this? Bonus points for documentation I can share with our hardware vendor.

Comment: I wonder if these Windows S mode driver requirements are what I am looking for. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/windows10sdriverrequirements

Answer (score 0):

The basic input and output devices drivers will be survive easily, like USB, Mouse, Keyboard, Monitor etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for something more specific. A particular class of driver or whether some are not being added to the driver store. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/getting-started-with-windows-drivers